# BigQuery : case when expression to Count from Same column but different conditions

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table with 2 columns  as below:

```
Col 1    | col_stats
Field 1  |   open
Field 2  |   close
Field 1  |   close
Field 1  |   open
```

**I want the ouput to be as :**

```
Col1    | cnt_open | Cnt_close
Field 1 |  2          | 1             
Field 2 |  0          | 1
```

**I wrote a query **

```
select col 1, count(case when col_stats= 'open' then 1 else 0 END) cnt_open,
count (case when col_stats= 'close' then 1 else 0  END ) cnt_close 
from `project.dataset.tablename`
group by col1
```

**Resultant output from above query is incorrect:**

```
Col1    | cnt_open | Cnt_close  
Field 1 |  2          | 2             
Field 2 |  1          | 1
```

Can somebody let me know why the output is giving incorrect result for count even after case condition is applied?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `countif()`:

```
select col1, countif(col_stat = 'open') as num_opens, countif(col_stat = 'closed') as num_closes
from t
group by col1;
```

In SQL `count()` counts the number of non-`NULL` values.  Your code would work with `sum()`.  But `countif()` is simpler and clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Use `null` instead of `0`:

```
select col1, count(case when col_stats= 'open' then 1 else null END) cnt_open,
count (case when col_stats= 'close' then 1 else null  END ) cnt_close 
from `project.dataset.tablename`
group by col1
```